# Javascript Table Sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to implement a table sorting function.

It requires keeping the classes and some data attributes on `<td>`'s and `<tr>`'s so I'm doing it slightly differently than I've seen in other examples.

I'm using `localeCompare()` in the sorting function. The problem I'm having is that after sorting the **first** and **seventh** item in the list are out of order - the rest seems to be in order. I've tried altering the sort function using `> <` instead and I have the same result.

Could anyone have a glance over my code and see if there's a glaring mistake I'm missing please?

I've tested in on every column it's always the 1st & 7th.

[image]

```
var sort = function() {

        var tbody    = document.getElementById(tbody_id),
            rows_len = tbody.rows.length,
            col_len  = tbody.rows[0].cells.length;

        //console.log(rows_len, col_len);

        var order_hash = [];    

        //loop rows
        for(var i = 0; i < rows_len; i++) {

            order_hash[i] = {
                value:tbody.rows[i].cells[column].innerHTML,
                html: tbody.rows[i].outerHTML
            };

        }

        console.log(order_hash);

        order_hash.sort(function(a, b) {

            var result = a.value.localeCompare(b.value);

            return (order == 'asc') ? result : (result == 0) ? 0 : (result < 1) ? 1 : -1;

        });

        order_hash.sort();

        var html = '';

        for(var i = 0; i < rows_len; i++) {
            html += order_hash[i].html;
        }

        tbody.innerHTML = html;

        order = undefined;
        delete(order_hash);

    };



}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling sort method twice (one custom and one standard), so the second sort will sort the `order_hash` in inconsistent way because:

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting
>   them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For
>   example, "Cherry" comes before "banana". In a numeric sort, 9 comes
>   before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes
>   before "9" in Unicode order.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Remove the second sort and will work fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wf9o2tg8/

Comment: Ah right you are that worked, thanks for that much appreciated